# Iterate over email templates to check when it was last time sent

Tags: laravel

Every email I am sending through my code has it's template stored on next path `resources\views\emails`. Is there a way to create a function which would iterate over those templates and return an array with times when those templates were last time called from some part in my code?

Comment: That would only be possible, if you store it inside your database or something else

Comment: You mean every time I send an email, I should store the current time and the template which was used for creating that email?

Comment: Yes, because it isn't possible to get the date a file was opened the last time

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a great way to achieve what I need! Will use it

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the database and check before you trigger the email.

Hope this will be useful for you.
Saving Or Logging the emails in laravel tutorial.
https://www.sitepoint.com/mail-logging-in-laravel-5-3-extending-the-mail-driver/

Answer (score 0):

I think Raza Rafaideen is correct, you'll probably have to store the events in the database. If you don't want to have to build the logging storage in the database yourself, there are packages to do it. I used this one about a year ago and it seemed to work out well:

https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log